# Can't run vagrant in virtual servers@Bluemix

Tags: vagrant, ibm-cloud

Received following error message, any limitation?

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: `["startvm", "35f14b2c-88dc-415a-8634-97132afeff1d", "--type", "headless"]`

Stderr:

> VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005),
>   component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Answer (score 0):

It seem like virtualization is not enabled or not support in your system. first you have to enable it from BIOS if it support virtualization.